# Migrating mono-based web application from .net 2 to .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono

I have an issue migrating our web application, which was written 5 years ago with Mono version 2.10.8.3.

We decided to change our server and installed ubuntu 14.04, which includes Mono version 4.2.3. If we open our solution in the newer version of MonoDevelop and compile it targetting the new framework version 4.5, after fixing some version errors, we run the application but we get this runtime exception, which in debug mode throws:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

This is the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="custom_report" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="some_connection_string" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  <!--<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" localOnly="true" />-->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
    <pages styleSheetTheme="WinXP_Blue" enableEventValidation="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
        <add tagPrefix="rovshan" namespace="TelecomBilling" assembly="TelecomBilling, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <add tagPrefix="mark" assembly="Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker" namespace="Mark.Web.UI.WebControls" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="GET" path="/JavascriptDateTimeFormat.axd" type="Mark.Web.UI.JavascriptDateTimeFormat, Mark.Web.UI.WebControls.DateTimePicker" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!-- Uncomment this line to customize maxJsonLength and add a custom converter -->
        <!--
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500">
        <converters>
          <add name="ConvertMe" type="Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter"/>
        </converters>
      </jsonSerialization>
      -->
        <!-- Uncomment this line to enable the authentication service. Include requireSSL="true" if appropriate. -->
        <!--
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
      -->
        <!-- Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service. To allow profile properties to be retrieved
           and modified in ASP.NET AJAX applications, you need to add each property name to the readAccessProperties and
           writeAccessProperties attributes. -->
        <!--
      <profileService enabled="true"
                      readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                      writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
      -->
      </webServices>
      <!--
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
      -->
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is no assembly System.Web.Entity.dll with local copy or in the GAC.
In VisualStudio we have tools to migrate from one version to another but in MonoDevelop I can not find anything similar. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I guess you mean ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @knocte ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 doesn't include mono 4.2.3, you must have installed it from external repositories

Comment: @knocte already installed.we don t have any issues with runtime!

Comment: what? please clarify your statement